# Generate depth map from one/two images?

Tags: linux, images, image-processing, image-recognition, artificial-intelligence

I want to generate a depth map from one image, [as Google's AI](https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/05/moving-camera-moving-people-deep.html). Or  [this](https://3dstereophoto.blogspot.com/p/software.html) super unpractical blog program does from at least two.

I know that exist some algorithms that do this from multiple images, but I have no idea which is the best.

If the software is available for Linux, better. Because Debian Buster is my main OS for now.